# Test Suite Failed to run

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, ts-jest

**Error**

> thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
> Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
>
> ```
>   24 |
> > 25 | afterAll(async () => {
>      | ^
>   26 |     jest.setTimeout(20000);
>   27 |     await mongo.stop();
>   28 |     await mongoose.connection.close();
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/setup.ts:25:1)
>   at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
> ```

Test Code

**setup.test.ts**

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { app } from '../app';

let mongo: any;

beforeAll(async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(10000);
    process.env.JWT_KEY = 'asdfasd';
    mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const uri = await mongo.getUri();

    await mongoose.connect(uri);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(10000);
    const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

    for(let collection of collections){
        await collection.deleteMany({});
    }
});

afterAll(async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    await mongo.stop();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
})
```

dependencies

> "mongodb-memory-server": "^8.0.4", "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
> "supertest": "^6.1.6", "ts-jest": "^27.1.2"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and as Cody mentioned, by increasing the "testTimeout" in my Jest config file, I managed to overcome this error.

Hope this helps other people encountering this error, thank you very much

My config file:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "verbose": true,
  "testTimeout": 1000000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The timeout is referring to the the test taking longer than 5000 ms.

You can set the test timeout programmatically although I don't think this can be done within a test (as you've shown above) it would need to be done in a global setup file like jest.setup.js

Alternateively, I would suggest setting the timeout in your jest.config.js

example:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testTimeout": 5000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it without editing the config file.
What I did is, I added as a second argument a new timeOut as you can see below:

```js
afterAll(async () => {
// your code here 
// your code here 
}, 100000)
```

Comment: This was the most scoped solution for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers(); // you must add this
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
    
describe('test', () => {
  it('should call spy', (() => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(storeFacade, 'notReadNotifications');
    const time = component["timeToCheckNotifications"] * 2 + 1
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(time);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
// this is the test of function used the timer like (setInterval)
  }));
});
    
afterEach(() => {
  jest.runOnlyPendingTimers() // you must add this
  jest.useRealTimers() // you must add this
})
      
// here you can add others describe
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Used this in `package.json` file..
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d83We.png)

Earlier, I was setting timeout in `beforeEach()` function. Setting timeout in `packgage.json` solved the issue